# trying to fetch on aws lambda using serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm trying to run a simple script on AWS Lambda using Serverless to push it, the script fetches a url and returns it (a proxy), for some reason I can't see the response.

The script in question:

```js
'use strict';
let axios = require('axios')

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  let res = await axios.get('http://example.com')
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: res,
      input: event,
    }),
  }
};
```

My serverless YML:

```js
service: get-soundcloud-tracks 
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  profile: home
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: users/create
          method: get
          cors: true
```

Comment: Wrap the await part of your code in a try catch block so you can see if axios is not failing? I suspect that the promise **await** gets back causes failure.

Comment: @squeekyDave, thanks but I tried it already, no errors...

Comment: Seems ok. But what do you see as a response. Does lambda timeout? Do console.log() and check cloudwatch logs

Comment: Thank @CanSahin, through Cloudwatch I was able to see that I should JSON.stringify `res.data`, and not `res`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was changing `res` to `res.data` inside the JSON.stringify